# How to group by with two columns and viceversa

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this kind of table

```
a_id | b_id
   1 |    2
   2 |    1
   2 |    1
   1 |    2
   3 |    1
   1 |    4
```

If its `1` I would like to get the different combinations that have `a_id=1` or `b_id=1` like

```
result
   2
   3
   4
```

Its like group by with two columns but using same values in each pair of columns (viceversa). Is it any possible way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union`:

```
select b_id as result from t where a_id = 1 union
select a_id from t where b_id = 1;
```

There are other methods . . . say, a lateral joi:

```
select distinct x.result
from t, lateral
      (values (case when a_id = 1 then b_id else a_id end) x(result)
where 1 in (a_id, b_id);
```

Or even the query more directly:

```
select distinct x(case when a_id = 1 then b_id else a_id end) as result
from t
where 1 in (a_id, b_id);
```

Because you are removing duplicates, the `distinct` is going to dominate performance of pretty much any method.

Comment: what if each row has a created_at and I'd like the result to be order by that created_at, with this the result should be `4,3,2`. Any way?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia . . . You should ask new questions as a question rather than  in a comment.